# Objective C - detect sound

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I detect sound on the iPhone?
I currently have it somewhat working using the method described in this article http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/

However, as mentioned in that article, in noisy rooms for example, the method won't work.
So in a way, I'm looking for methods that I can use to separate background noise from actual noise intended?

There probably won't be an existing code on the internet, but if someone can point me to the right direction, it would be very appreciated.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not a great solution, but you could determine a baseline amplitude (ambient sound) and trigger your events when you determine that the amplitude is a certain amount greater for a set amount of time.

Comment: Thanks jn_pdx, that's actually how I have it right now. Get the base noise and check if there is a noise greater than that. Problem with that is basically as I mentioned, when I'm in a noisy room say a bar, it's really hard to get the app to work correctly. Besides, when the background noise is at 90% loudness, to beat that I basically have to scream super hard. Not sure if there is a remedy to that. Thanks, Tee